# Download a file from SharePoint using REST API in VB.net

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file-download

My requirement is to download a file from SharePoint (to my local  machine) using Rest API and the code to be written in VB.net .

I have installed Visual Studio 2019  and I have the SharePoint link from where the file is to be downloaded. The file to be downloaded is excel file.

Below is the code I have tried but the code exits without any output.

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports Microsoft.Graph
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports RestSharp
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers
Imports Magnum.FileSystem
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Module Generating_access_token


    Public Class PostWrapper
        Public Response_Text() As Post
    End Class



    Public Sub Generate_Access_Token()
        Try

            Dim ClientId As String = "<client id>"
            Dim TenentId As String = "<tenant id>"
            Dim ClientSecret As String = "<client secret>"
            Dim TokenUrl As String = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<tenant id>/tokens/OAuth/2"


 'AccessToken

            Dim client = New RestClient(TokenUrl.ToString) With {
.Timeout = -1}
            Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials")
            request.AddParameter("client_id", ClientId + "@" + TenentId)
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", ClientSecret)
            request.AddParameter("resource", "00000003-0000-0Ff1-ce00-000000000000/<tenant>.sharepoint.com@" + TenentId)

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content)

            If response.IsSuccessful Then
                Dim Response_Text As String = response.Content.ToString
                Console.WriteLine(Response_Text.ToString)


                client = New RestClient("<web url>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file url>')/$value")
                client.Timeout = -1
                request = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <access token>")
                response = client.Execute(request)
                'Console.WriteLine(response.Content)


                'Dim client = New RestClient("<file url>')/$value")
                'client.Timeout = -1
                'Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.GET)
                'request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")
                'request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <access token>")
                'IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request)
                'Console.WriteLine(response.Content)

                'Dim outputStream As FileStream = New FileStream(Path & FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate Or FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
                'outputStream.Write(Response_Text, 0, Response_Text.Length)
                'outputStream.Flush(True)
                'outputStream.Close()

            End If


            '          

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: can anyone please respond back ?

Comment: Just a heads up, including client secrets, access tokens, tenant ids. and SharePoint URLs in your code sample can open you up to attack. I've edited the post to remove this type of information.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to REST API instead of the Client Object Model? The Client Object Model code will be simpler and easier to implement.